# ASP.Net image set ImageURL to external site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am struggling to set ImageURL in a asp:image control. I am setting it to a URL from another site, at the moment I have several versions of the image trying to get one to work bellow is my code and the output.

Function used in images bellow

```
Function BuildLogoPath() As String
    Return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "/img/main/logo.jpg"
End Function
```

ASP.net Code in page

```
<asp:Image ID="imgFav" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "img/favicon.ico" %>' /><br />
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "/img/main/logo.jpg" %>' />
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "/img/main/logo.jpg" %>' />
<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% Response.write(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "/img/main/logo.jpg") %>' />
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# BuildLogoPath() %>' /><br />
<asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%= BuildLogoPath() %>' />
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% BuildLogoPath() %>' />
<asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% response.write(BuildLogoPath()) %>' />
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "img/favicon.ico" %><br />
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath") & "/img/main/logo.jpg" %>
```

Output:

```
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imgFav" src="<%:%20ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(&quot;WebPath&quot;)%20&amp;%20&quot;img/favicon.ico&quot;%20%>"><br>
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image2" src="<%=%20ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(&quot;WebPath&quot;)%20&amp;%20&quot;/img/main/logo.jpg&quot;%20%>">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image3" src="<%%20ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(&quot;WebPath&quot;)%20&amp;%20&quot;/img/main/logo.jpg&quot;%20%>">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image4" src="<%%20Response.write(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(&quot;WebPath&quot;)%20&amp;%20&quot;/img/main/logo.jpg&quot;)%20%>">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imgLogo" src=""><br>
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image5" src="<%=%20BuildLogoPath()%20%>">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image6" src="<%%20BuildLogoPath()%20%>">
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Image7" src="<%%20response.write(BuildLogoPath())%20%>">
http://office.logma.biz/onefit.com.jamie/img/favicon.ico<br>
http://office.logma.biz/onefit.com.jamie//img/main/logo.jpg
```

As you can see the code is working fine when not not in the image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't use `<%` and `%>` inside `<asp: .. />` tags. You have two options:

1. Set it programmatically from code-behind:

   imgFav.ImageUrl = Me.BuildLogoPath()
2. Render a normal `<img>` tag in the HTML instead:

   `<img src='<%= BuildLogoPath() %>' />`

Comment: Method 1 worked but method 2 produced a similar result to what I was already getting

CODE:`<img runat="server" src='<%= BuildLogoPath() %>'/>`

RESULT:`<img src="<%= BuildLogoPath() %>"></img>`

Comment: @Blag You need to drop the `runat="server"` to get it working - the point is that you want it to be a normal HTML image, not a server control at all.